# Pokemon go account "gone"

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I'm trying to help my nephew who all of the sudden can't log in to his account. 
He downloaded the game with an Australian account before it came to Denmark, and have been playing for a while. 
Today he accidentally preset something about starting a new game, and then everything he had been working on disappeared. 
He says that to log in, he used the option to log in with gmail and with Pokemon trainer account and he always chose the gmail option. Now the gmail option is gone, and when he tries to log in using the Pokemon trainer log in, is says that his username does not exist.

Does this make sense to anyone, and does anyone know if he can he retrieve his old data??

Comment: This is what happens to lazy people not caring about the birth date when the app asks for it :)

Comment: He put his correct birthday, but he's only 12. Is that the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app and then inputting an older birthday (probably 13 or above) and then the gmail option should show up. I have not tested this and if anyone else has a better answer please post it.